# how to pass query parameter for get method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have rest API built in WSO2 ESB.
This is my request in service for POST method.

```
createUser: function(aUser) {
            var myCreateUserRequest =  {
                       "User":    {
                          "UserName": aUser.Username,
                          "UserPassword": aUser.Password,
                          "OrganizationId": aUser.OrgId,
                          "UserStatus": "Active", }}          
            //API Call
            var promise = $http.post(API_URL,myCreateUserRequest,REQUEST_HEADER).then(
            function(aCreateUserResponse) { 
                return [aCreateUserResponse.data.CreateUserResponse.Result.ResponseCode,''];
            });
             return promise; },
```

NOW similarly I want to pass only 2 parameter to GET a user i.e UserName and Organization id. How can I do that in angular js?
What I have implemented so far is:

```
getUser: function() {
            params =  {"UserName": aUser.Username, "OrganizationId": aUser.OrgId}         
            //API Call
            var promise = $http.get(API_URL,params,REQUEST_HEADER).then(
            function(aGetUserResponse) { 
                return [aGetUserResponse.data.GetUserResponse.Result,''];
            });
             return promise; },
```

Is this is the correct way to do else how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't correct, as POST has a data parameter, GET does not (because there is no body in Get request). [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

In order to pass those parameters, you need to add them to the URL as querystrings

Comment: What is the exact syntax?

Comment: There isn't a syntax for this - a put request just needs the right querystring - http://mysite/api/method?UserName=abc123&OrganizationId=def456

Comment: Link is not working and u means just to send parameter with url ?

Comment: Yes. A get request needs the parameters as a part of the URL. (also I fixed the link. )

Comment: now i am passing parameters but my sequence is changing that is why I am getting 404.